# Convertir fecha en formato normal

Tags: javascript

tengo esta fecha `2018-08-24T04:47:51.000Z` en un formato desconocido

como lo convierto en formato normal, con javascript?

debo usar la libreria moment obligatoriamente?

Comment: de donde llega ese valor? es dinámico estático? lo generas en el frontend o en el backend?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz guardo date() en la bd y asi lo guarda

Comment: @AlfredoPaz cuando lo recupero de mi bd lo obtengo en ese formato

Comment: Qué lenguaje back-end estás usando?

Comment: @AndySamuel javascript, con el framework expressjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te comento que puedes usar la función de MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` que como primer argumento recibe la variable o columna donde tienes almacenada la fecha que deseas mejorar en su formato; posterior el segundo argumento entre comillas es el formato que deseas te arroje en consola

Te dejo este ejemplo, que te debería ayudar a devolver formateada la fecha desde la propia base de datos para evitar otorgar esa tarea o al backend o al frontend aunque claro se puede hacer

Ejemplo

```
MariaDB [blog]> SET @Fecha = '2018-08-24T04:47:51.000Z';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [blog]> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(@Fecha, '%d/%m/%Y');
+---------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(@Fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') |
+---------------------------------+
| 24/08/2018                      |
+---------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.000 sec)
```

La función `DATE_FORMAT()` recibe como primer parámetro la fecha y como segundo la máscara que formateará los datos

```
DATE_FORMAT(fecha, máscara_a_usar);
```

Comment: pero no obtengo solo la fecha, obtengo mas atributos y como uso date_format en ese caso?

Comment: @hubman si notas en el ejemplo use tu mismo ejemplo de fecha, pero el colocar la máscara %d/%m/%Y limito a que la fecha se quede como dia mes y año aunque originalmente traiga mas datos